# Code relying on exif_read_data() stops producing expected output

Tags: php, exif

I have a photoblog which prints out EXIF info from my images (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php).

Worked great, until today. It just stopped printing out the data. I have not made any changes to the files.

The images are located in wordpress upload folder. If i try with an image+exif php file in public_html, i get the data as usual. What could have caused this? Thanks!

Comment: This has most likely to do with user rights in your upload folder. Try doing a manual call and see what errors you get (you should get some)

Comment: Are you using a shared server? Could some one have messed with the Php configuration?

Comment: The hosting is one.com. I dont think i can get the file to print any php errors on this host.

Comment: Forgot to mention that ive tried with adding chmod 777 to all the wordpress folders. without success

Answer (score 0):

If the images are being loaded the same way, there have been no changes to code as you indicate, then the only conclusion is that the images no longer contain EXIF data, or the method of encoding has changed.

Compare all EXIF tags from an image during the functional period to a current one. There must be some difference in the input.

Comment: The images still contains the data. Like i said above: if i put an image + a php file containing the read exif function in the public_html, it works. But not in the wp dir.

Comment: As other comments suggest, the problem may be one with changed permissions on the input folder.

Answer (score 0):

> Worked great, until today.

As it just stopped working I would guess that its something to do with your shared server. Have a look at your Php configuration, and see if "EXIF Support" is enabled. 
You can call phpinfo() like this:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

If there is an issue with Php configuration, there are workarounds (some shared hosting allow you to configure php by using a .htaccess or adding php.ini file to a directory, containing the settings that are to be overridden, but you might be better getting in contact with your shared hosting provider).